# String manipulation to automate file export

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a lot of files in a directory that I import using

```
files = FileNames["*.csv", "/Users/jazz/Downloads/second_data_set"];
```

I can then import each file in `files` and edit as necessary. As an example presume:

```
files[[1]] = "Users/Desktop/Data/results.csv"
```

I would like to export to a different directory and as a different file extension. Say I want to edit the file `results.csv` and save it instead as `results.dat` in the directory "Users/Desktop/".

This requires text manipulation on `files[[1]]`. Any ideas on how to change this? Specifically, I want to automate this since I am looping over files and so have lots of files to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this (not tested):

```
Do[
 data = Import[file];
 (*manipulate data here*)
 Export[
  FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", FileBaseName[file] <> ".dat"}],
  data
  ],
 {file, FileNames["*.csv", FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory,"Downloads","second_data_set"}]}
 ]
```

Other useful commands are `DirectoryName`, `FileExtension`, and `ParentDirectory`.

Comment: Basically that is what my answer would also be. I think `DirectoryName` is also a function worth mentioning (maybe `FileDirectory` was a typo and you meant DirectoryName?). It basically does the same thing as `ParentDirectory` but is less picky about what it accepts as input (`ParentDirectory` e.g. wants directories only and complains when these do not exist yet)

Comment: Thanks Abert! Indeed `FileDirectory` was a typo. I meant `DirectoryName`.

Comment: You are welcome...